# A circular control reference has been made. A control cannot be owned by or parented to itself

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Metro ui for windows application

```
public partial class Distributor_Closing : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
 private object BtnClick(Button button, int index)
        {
    MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm childForm = new Distributer_Closing_Info(sub_cat[index], Str, id, Convert.ToInt32(Mtddlstocks.SelectedValue));
                childForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
}
```

I am getting above error when i close  Distributer_Closing_Info child form;

```
 public partial class Distributer_Closing_Info : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
 public Distributer_Closing_Info(int sub_cat,String dte,int stk_mas,int stkid)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sub_catid = sub_cat;
            StockDate = dte;
            Stkmasid = Convert.ToInt32(stk_mas);
            stk_id = stkid;
            LoadGrid();

        }
}
```

Comment: Try `childForm.ShowDialog(null);` instead.

Comment: Hmmm..Thanks it worked!!!

Comment: The problem is Using Metro Framework. I used Metro Framework this error is shown and then I changed to normal windows form then it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with the using MetroForm from the MetroFramework;
Your program would work fine if you were using System.Windows.Forms.Form

The workaround as mentioned

```
childForm.ShowDialog(null);
```

or this one

```
childForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following line triggered this exception (WinForms):

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
```

(The SplitContainer added itself in one of it's own panels.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I no longer could open a Form in the WinForms designer within Visual Studio. I received the "A circular control reference has been made" error.

It turns out that I had set the .Name property of the Form to the same name as one of the Controls on the Form (I might have done this by editing the .Designer.cs code indirectly using a ReSharper rename operation...) in the .Designer.cs class module using the same name (but different casing) as a control already declared as private.

For example, the designer code had this snippet for setting Form properties:

```
            // 
            // MyForm 
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(850, 613);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "MyCircularName";
```

While further down in the .Designer.cs, control names are declared:

```
private MyUserControl myCircularName;
```

Notice that "MyCircularName" is now used by both Form and MyUserControl instances (the circular-check is not case sensitive). When I try to view the Form in the designer, the designer detects that my Form Name property is the same as a declared-control's Name property.

The solution was to either rename the Form (change "MyCircularName" to, say, "MyCircularNameForm") or to change the declared control name from "myCircularName" to, say, "myCircularNameControl".